# There is isomorphism $T:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $Tx_n = y_n$ for each $n$ implies $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

I am reading the book 'Topics in Banach Space Theory'.

Notations: $[x_n]$ denotes the closed linear span of $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}.$ Two bases $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are equivalent if for all sequence of scalars $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n y_n$ converges.

> Theorem: $1.3.2 \space $Two bases ( or basic sequences) $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are equivalent if and only if there is an isomorphism $T: [x_n] \rightarrow [y_n]$ such that $Tx_n = y_n$ for each $n$.

Proof: $(\Leftarrow)$ Let $X = [x_n]$ and $Y=[y_n]$. It is obvious that $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are equivalent if there is an isomorphism $T$ from $X$ onto $Y$ such that $Tx_n = y_n$ for each $n$.

I try to fill in the 'obvious' part. Suppose $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of scalars such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n x_n}$ converges. By the definition of $T$, we have $T(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n x_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n y_n$ (I do not know whether I can do this or not).

I feel like $T$ is just like a rearrangement of a series in another space. But we know that rearrangement does not always preserve convergence. It seems like the obvious part is not obvious to me.

Comment: Use the fact that convergence is equivalent to Cauhy property,  by definition of Banach spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Tx_n=y_n$ then by linearity we get
$$
T\left(\sum_{k=1}^Na_kx_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^Na_ky_k.
$$
If the partial sum for $x$ converges (to $x=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_kx_k$) then by continuity of $T$ the partial sum for $y$ must converge too (to $T(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_ky_k$). The other way round is similar, because $T^{-1}$ is continuous as well.